# Accessing child element property through parent element property with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to show a child element property from 'select' tag and I using `document.getElementsByTagName` command to do that, the display that I expect is 'john dalton' look source bellow!, but browser not display as I expect just undefined message in alert. my source like this:

```
<select  style=""  name="provinsi_id" class="form-control crud-edit 
  lookup-refresh" onchange="showoption();">
<option>john dalton</option>
<option>john rambo</option>
<script>
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].childNodes[0].value);
<script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].childNodes[1].value);
```

0th element is a text element.

[Note: Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes. Comments are also considered as nodes.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp)

Comment: not working guys, can u run my complete script in your browser and respon the answer in this forum,please!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a `<select>` you can access to the options easily.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options
```

The "options" is an **array of all the options** in your select, so you can acces to your value this way:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options[0].value
```

You also have a shortcut by doing this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0][0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

every answer runing well, if I write static code as  Nannakuhtum's sample,  unfortunately in my case  I use javascript to fill option  value dynamicly like this,

```
<html>
--------
 <select  style=""  name="provinsi_id" 
class="form-control crud-edit 
lookup-refresh" onchange="tampilkota();">
</select>
------------
</html>



<script>
var dataprovinsi = <?php echo json_encode($dataprovinsi); ?>;
for (i=0; i< dataprovinsi.length; i++){
var option  = document.createElement("option");
option.text     = dataprovinsi[i]['nama'];
option.value    = dataprovinsi[i]['nama'];
var select  = document.getElementById("psg_provinsi_id");
select.appendChild(option);
}

function tampilkota(){
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].childNodes[1].value);
}
```